# What can I do if the system I want to install an OS on doesn't provide drivers for that OS?

Tags: laptop, drivers, windows-server-2008

I've got a spare laptop at home that I'd like to put Server 2008 on to use as a small, personal web server and web radio station, although the HP Laptop doesn't have drivers for Server 2008. Vista and 7, sure, but not 2008. I've tried installing the wireless/LAN drivers from 7 as AFAIK it's a similar base.

I would be OK using 7 or XP as a host for a web server and using WAMP to do the hosting but the reason I'm primarily after 2008 is Windows Media Streaming for which I hope to use for the internet radio.

Another option is put a Linux distro such as Ubuntu on it and see if that will find the drivers and then find a radio programme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an OS that is supported, identify all of the device/chipset manufacturers or models.  Then go to the manufacturer websites and see if the appropriate driver can be found there.  Like, getting a NIC driver from Broadcom's website directly instead of through HP.

Comment: this is a good idea, I will try and hope it works.

Comment: broadcom don't provide a 2008 driver, so I've put Win 7 on it instead. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

The windows server 2008 architecture with all intents and purposes of what your using it for is the same as windows 7.  Drivers that work for windows 7 *should* work for win server 2k8.  You may also have success in stalling vista drivers as well.

Comment: I'll try and find the drivers via the way given in @DHayes answer. I know it *should* work but we shall see.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to use a Linux distro (probably Debian), but that's just because I'm familiar with it.  You could certainly stick to Win7 and stream using, e.g., VLC or ffmpeg.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, is there a Debian package for streaming? Thanks for the suggestion about VLC, seems to be ok for LAN streaming, but over internet it gets a bit more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

In the case there is really no driver available for the target OS with your hardware and there are no alternative OS / software that would fill the gap, you still have the possibility to first install a virtualization layer on your box (VirtualBox, Xen, KVM and the likes) and then install the wanted OS as a guest.